# Getting notice is wordpress "WP_Scripts::localize was called incorrectly"

Tags: wordpress

Complete message:
Notice: WP_Scripts::localize was called incorrectly. The $l10n parameter must be an array. To pass arbitrary data to scripts, use the wp_add_inline_script() function instead. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 5.7.0.) in /home3/dduconne/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313

Appeared just after updating wordpress to 5.7.0

Comment: I saw the WP Accessibility plugin cause this issue, but I'm sure it's not the only one. If you're curious about which of your plugins is causing it, disable them one at a time until it disappears, then you'll know which one is responsible!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a new warning appearing in Wordpress 5.7. If you don't want to see it, and still want to have WP_DEBUG set to true, it is possible to disable the message by adding the following for example in your theme's functions.php:

```
 add_filter('doing_it_wrong_trigger_error', function () {return false;}, 10, 0);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem it only sweeps it under the rug.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for now. Let's wait the real fix from WP.

Comment: Very bad advice and this answer should ***NOT BE ACCEPTED***. It doesn't solve anything.

Comment: I invite those who complain about my answer to come up with a better one. OF COURSE my answer does not solve the problem, since the problem lies in one or several of the plugins used. If you're a plugin author you must of course fix the problem (which - I stress - went unnoticed until now), by making sure that the third param of wp_localize_script is an array. But if you're not, what are the options? Patching the faulting plugins? Not a sustainable solution (been there done that). Set WP_DEBUG to false? Much worse than my answer since it disables not only this warning but many others.

Comment: Actually the "problem" is looking at the endless list of errors which are unavoidable due to WP not having the resources to fix the issue. Yes plugins and themes could revert to a fallback in some function, but this does not SOLVE the inherit "problem." Yet is does SOLVE the initial problem of having to look at the redundant error text on your page; when in all practicality, you could be using that head space for something more relevant, like  errors you CAN fix.

I 1 up-ed the answer as it DID help me. The instance I was working on had way too many plugins to isolate the error source.

Answer (score 25):

Ok since there quite a few views and the previous answer just throws it under the rug.

Yes it is a warning now, but who knows what will happen, it is a warning for a reason, disabling something is not resolving it, there is a reason devs set it as a warning for now.

While we wait for plugin developers to resolve it on their ends, you can find out the source of the problem by enabling `php_xdebug` in php. I recommend not leaving it after debugging, as I am not sure about the performance cost of it being enabled.

`php_xdebug` will return a stack of all files affected, from there you can trace it to the source of the problem. The fix once found the source is quite easy. Culprit most likely is [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) which requires last parameter to be an `array()`!

So you would find something like this:

```
wp_localize_script( 'handle', 'object_name', 'l10n_culprit_string' );
```

Which should be turned into:

```
wp_localize_script( 'handle', 'object_name', array( 'l10n_culprit_string' ) );
```

Solution to problem came from [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-error-on-wp-5-7/)

Comment: this one should be the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Notice also that the original intention behind `wp_localize_script` was handling translatable strings in js. We've all been using it as a hack to pass global values to scripts, not just translatable strings for years. It can still be used that way and it will work, but apparently, it's better practice to use `wp_add_inline_script` now instead. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/#comment-4632

Answer (score 0):

It is now a notice if you are using wp5.7 and php7.4, but changing to php8 it may gets reported as error. For me, when i changed (in my own code) the passed value to array (yes, probably some changes also needed in the involved js), everything worked just fine.

Comment: Hi @dominagy - this is a great comment and important info (that it gets reported as an error when you switch to PHP8). Probably more appropriate as a comment on GhostPengy's answer. I would upvote it as a comment under that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because one of the PHP script in your wordpress installation uses wp_localize_script() to pass some PHP variables to a JS script through AJAX request, and it's not good practice anymore.
This can be inside a plugin or inside your custom theme or child-theme's functions.php.
If wp_localize_script() is not in a child-theme or custom theme's functions.php, try this :

1. backup your website
2. deactivate all plugins
3. reactivate them one by one until you get the notice again
4. when the notice shows up again, this means the plugin you just reactivated uses wp_localize_script() the wrong way
5. if it's not up-to-date, try updating it (if you want to) : maybe the notice is going to disappear
6. if it's already up-to-date, or you don't want to update it, search inside wp-content/plugins the corresponding plugin's folder
7. open it and try to find the file(s) where wp_localize_script() is called, you can also use CLI with your server's terminal to find string in files. For example, if your server runs on Linux : grep -H -r "wp_localize_script()" /root/pathtopluginfolder | cut -d: -f1
8. Then, replace the code as follow :

Old one should look almost like this :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpdocs-my-script', 'https://url-to/my-script.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'wpdocs-my-script', 'MYSCRIPT', array(
    'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'otherParam' => 'some value',
) );
```

New one :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpdocs-my-script', 'https://url-to/my-script.js' );
wp_add_inline_script( 'wpdocs-my-script', 'const MYSCRIPT = ' . json_encode( array(
    'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'otherParam' => 'some value',
) ), 'before' );
```

**Note that you need to add 'before' as the third parameter to the wp_add_inline_script function.**

Once it's done, the notice shouldn't show anymore. If so, contact the plugin dev to tell him about this so that it can be part of the next update.

For more informations, see Jules Colle's comment on this page : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/